# Why is malloc giving me 8 bytes when I request 20?

Tags: c, malloc, sizeof

I've just been playing around in C for the first time, and I'm at a loss as to why malloc is not giving me the amount of memory that I'd expect it to. The following code:

```
printf("Allocating %ld bytes of memory\n", 5*sizeof(int));
int *array = (int *) malloc(5*sizeof(int));
printf("%ld bytes of memory allocated\n", sizeof(array));
```

results in:

```
Allocating 20 bytes of memory
8 bytes of memory allocated
```

I've checked that I'm indeed calling malloc to give me 20 bytes, but don't understand why after calling malloc, the pointer only has 8 bytes.

Comment: `array` is a pointer. `sizeof (array)` gives you the size of the pointer, not of the allocated array. You can't use `sizeof` to determine the size of a `malloc`-allocated chunk of memory.

Comment: Because 8 is the size of the pointer variable.

Comment: If `malloc` does not return `NULL` it allocated the amount of memory you requested. That is what you should be checking.

Comment: You asked for `sizeof(array)` - don't be surprised that it told you the size of `array`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`array` is not an array but an `int *`.  So it's size will always be the size of the pointer.

The `sizeof` operator does not tell you how much memory was dynamically allocated at a pointer.

If on the other hand you had this:

```
int array2[5];
```

Then `sizeof(array2)` would be 20, assuming an `int` is 4 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

The `sizeof` operator tells you the size of its operand. `array` has type `int*` (pointer to `int`) which occupies eight bytes on your platform. The `sizeof` operator cannot find out how long the array `array` points to actually is. What is returns is not indicative about how much memory has been allocated.

The `malloc()` function either fails (in which case it returns `NULL`) or succeeds in which case it returns a pointer to a memory region at least as large as you need it.